# SQL Command Not Properly Ended - Using 'As' on Union

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to combine three `select`s with a `union` and then apply a `where` to the union result. I am receiving a 'SQL command not properly ended' error on the line where I have `as U`.

```
select *
from (
    select A.model, A.price
    from PC A
    union
    select B.model, B.price
    from Laptop B
    union
    select C.model, C.price
    from Printer C
) as U
where U.model in (
    select D.model
    from Product D
    where D.maker = 'B');
```

Error aside, is there a better way to accomplish this? I am trying to get all results (two attributes, model and price) from three tables where an attribute in those tables (model) matches an attribute (maker) in a forth table.

Edit:

I do have it working as the following code, but I wanted to simplify it.

```
select A.model, A.price
from PC A
where A.model in (select B.model from Product B where B.maker = 'B')
union
select C.model, C.price
from Laptop C
where C.model in (select D.model from Product D where D.maker = 'B')
union
select E.model, E.price
from Printer E
where E.model in (select F.model from Product F where F.maker = 'B');
```

Comment: The "simplification" also reduces the number rows you're working BEFORE you union, so will probably be more efficient (I'm not an Oracle guy, so can't be sure they don't have an optimization that could kick in). Someone else may clarify, but I'm not all that sure that the original form with the WHERE after the union of everything would be able to use an index if it exists.

Comment: @JimL - even without being an Oracle guy, you had the right instinct. Absolutely Oracle has an optimizer that will push the predicate down to the base tables, if it determines that doing so will result in faster execution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need  just the name   for table .. (and eventually after named  you can assign an alias)

```
  select *
  from (
      select A.model, A.price
      from PC A
      union
      select B.model, B.price
      from Laptop B
      union
      select C.model, C.price
      from Printer C
  )  U
  where U.model in (
      select D.model
      from Product D
      where D.maker = 'B');
```

for the second part .. there si not other solution for  unit the table .. if you need  a sum of sets  you must use union  .. ( sets theory)

Answer (score 1):

So - the error: in Oracle the keyword `AS` can be used *optionally* before a column alias, and it is *prohibited* before an inline view alias.

Better query? Absolutely. It seems your `union` is for "model" and "price" from three *disjoint* lists - PC's, laptops, and printers. If so, then `union` has the same effect as `union all` but it will make the query slower, or possibly much slower.

Rewrite everything with `union all` instead of `union` and enjoy the gains.